# Background work is not kept working even with foreground service and alarm manager

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to count step 24/7.

So I create `Service()` and register notification in `onStartCommand()` and return START_STICKY.

However among 4 devices that I test with, 1 device keep stopped to count step on background.

So register alarmManager with 15minutes interval and to wake up device from doze mode, and in broadcast, if notification is not there, make call again service.

```
 alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val repeatInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES
        val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatInterval
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            triggerTime,
            repeatInterval,
            pendingIntent
        )
```

in broadcast receiver:

```
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val now = LocalDateTime.now()

        Log.d("알람매니저: 리시브", "${now}")

        // 브로드캐스트 주기적 등록
        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
        alarmIntent.setAction("ALARM_BROADCAST_RECEIVER")
        alarmIntent.putExtra("alarm", true)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context!!).sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);

        // 노티피케이션 서비스 호출
        val mNotificationManager =
            context?.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val statusNotifications = mNotificationManager.activeNotifications
        for (statusNotification in statusNotifications) {
            if (statusNotification.id == MyService.NOTIFICATION_ID) {
                // null
            } else {
                // 노티피케이션 없는 경우

                alarmIntent.setAction("ALARM_BROADCAST_RECEIVER")
                alarmIntent.putExtra("no_noti", true)
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context!!).sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);

                val startService = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startService);
                } else {
                    context.startService(startService);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

since I keep struggled with this, from broadcast receiver I send another local broadcast receiver when receiver is called and write it on my db.

for 2days, it works well, but after 2days, 1 device that kept stopped is also stopped again.

I check alarm broadcast receiver is no longer called.

I also set `battery usage` from optimization to no restriction..

I think I've done everything that i can do for making phone work on background.

I don't know what makes it stopped..

I know that it's hard to make it all time wake up, but I know a couple of apps that keep tracking steps on background, and I need to know how it's possible.

Please please help me.

I can also do chat!